# Get storageReference using image URL link

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-admin

Is there a way to do this via the admin SDK? I am able to do this via the client SDK. I am baffled as to why admin SDK seems to lack many features that clients have. How do I get storage reference using a download URL in admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDK for Storage is a fairly thin wrapper around the Google Cloud Storage SDK for that platform, mostly providing auto-initialization of the default bucket that Firebase uses. It does not expose any Firebase-specific functionality, such as mapping from download URLs back to a path in the bucket.

It's a valid request though, so you could [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).